# How to join objects through via multiple join tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have three models: `Event`, `Gallery` and `Image`.  An `Image` is the base model, and represents a single piece of media.  A `Gallery` is a collection of `Images` submitted by a user.  Users only interact with `Images` on the `Gallery` level, in that they create, modify and delete groups of `Images` at the time in the form of singular `Galleries`.  An `Event` is a collection of `Galleries` which associate the content with specific real-world events.

So, my relations are as follows: `Event -> Event_Galleries -> Gallery -> Gallery_Images -> Image`

My question is, through Bookshelf, is there a way to specify a relationship from the `Event` to the `Image` using both the existing join tables?  It would function as follows:

`Event
-> Event_Galleries where Event_Galleries.event_id = Event.id
-> Gallery_Image where Event_Galleries.gallery_id = Gallery_Image.gallery_id
-> Image where Image.id = Gallery_Image.image_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify relationships in a Bookshelf.js model, following this way :

```
const Company = db.bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'companys',
    hunters: function employees() {
        return this.hasMany(Employee, 'company_id');
    }
});

const Employee = db.bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'employees',
    company: function company() {
        return this.belongsTo(Company);
    },
    addresses: function addresses() {
        return this.hasMany(EmployeeAddress);
    },
});

const EmployeeAddress = db.bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'employees_addresses',
    employee: function employee() {
        return this.belongsTo(Employee);
    }
});

Company.where({ id: 42 }).fetch([ withRelated: 'employees', 'employees.addresses' ])
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
})
```